# Strapi endpoint for all media uploads

Tags: strapi

Does anyone know the endpoint for getting all of the iamges you uploaded to the media libray in one request?
Im using next js with strapi and need a way to grab all of the images from the media library but there doesnt seem to be any documentation on this

Answer (score 6):

/api/upload

1. GET  /api/upload/files   Get a list of files
2. GET  /api/upload/files/:id   Get a specific file
3. POST /api/upload Upload files
4. DELETE   /api/upload/files/:id   Delete a file

Reference
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#configuration

Comment: this gives 403 error

Comment: You will have to give permissions for find and findOne in settings > USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN > Roles > authenticated > upload

Answer (score 2):

GET `/upload/files`

You can read more on [the docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [plugin](https://github.com/dej10/strapi-plugin-file-system) I developed that could help, It can get folders and files in the folder aswell